# Question about iPod/iTunes

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, music, ipod

My husband has a older iPod nano.  He has music on it that he put in himself from cd's which were misplaced in a move.  He also has music from iTunes.  In addition, since I have an android phone, I have been buying music through Amazon music.  I'd love to get him a new iPod touch for Christmas to make it easier for him to add and remove music but I'm worried that his non iTunes music won't transfer over and the Amazon music won't be able to be used.  Can anyone tell me if that will be an issue? And if so, is there something specific I can do to make it all work? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your title to be relevant to the actual problem you are facing. A nondescript title obfuscates the content of the question.

Comment: How did your husband transfer his non-iTunes music to the iPod? Via iTunes or via other means?

Answer (score 1):

As long as the songs are still present inside his library in iTunes, all the songs are still available to sync over to the new iPod touch.

Also, you should be able to sync his old iPod nano to iTunes to get the songs back in the event that they are not in the library.

Comment: Syncing from iPad to iTunes may require additional software though...

Comment: @patrix I don't think I understand

Comment: You can't sync back audio tracks if the iDevice in question didn't sync with the specific iTunes installation in the first place. In this situation you need software like Senuti to copy tracks from the iDevice back to your computer.